# giving active colour to expansion panel in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to give a color to the expansion panel in material ui when it is open.
How can we overwrite this in material ui ?
Here is the link to 
https://codesandbox.io/s/yp9lmvwo1x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite the [`expanded`](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel/#css) class - check out [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wpxl8rwww)

Comment: I only want the expansion panel1 written header to turn blue .Another thing is that I don't see expansionpanel1 to be closing and all .

Comment: Remove the `expanded` prop passed to the expansion panel. Pass just the `classes` prop

Comment: It can't close, because the `expanded` property is set to `true`. I've updated the demo.

Comment: write classes in `styles` like this to make the heading text color change: `heading: {
    ...,
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  expandedPanel: {
    ...,
    color: 'red',
  }`
(Don't actually write `...` it just represents some other code you might have there.)

Comment: @LorenzHenk I have a span inside Expansion Label .Can we change the property of content inside span on basis of expand property of Expansion Panel ?

Comment: I basically wanted to change the colour of the font .I don't see fontColor property working .